# Returning a class - Object Oriented Programming Design Patterns

Tags: java, scala, oop, design-patterns, apache-spark

I'm trying to build a ETL-type module in scala for Spark. I have a base class transformer,

```
trait transformer{
  def transformer()
}
```

However then I extend this base class to two more types single return and multi return,

```
trait UnaryReturnTransformer extends transformer{
def inPorts()
def outPorts()
def setExpressions()
}

trait MultiReturnTransformer extends transformer{
def inPorts()
def outPorts()
def setExpressions()
}
```

Now, the actual implementation say, lookup transformer,

```
class LookupTransformer extends UnaryReturnTransformer{
//set local variables
//override functions
override def inports(df:DataFrane):

}
```

Is it better to return the class itself so that we could chain the code,
Eg,

```
new LookupTransformer().inports().setExpression().transform().Outports()
```

or make them as

```
val x=new LookupTransformer()
x.inports()
x.setExpression()
x.transform()
val ret=x.outPorts()
```

This seems more like a design question to me and It would be great to know what is the best practice to design such a system.

Thanks!

Comment: First one will be faster as in that case  pointer need not to jump on the next line again and again whereas in the second one it will be more readable form  and less error prone.

Comment: If possible I would consider using an immutable abstract class with value parameters as the base. Is there a reason why you have to use setters as opposed to class parameters?

Comment: @AmanChhabra What does *"First one will be faster as in that case pointer need not to jump on the next line again and again"* mean? Are you talking about the fact that he'll need to return a reference to the class on each method invocation? That'll be neglectable for performance. If he's using an immutable data structure that allocates a new object on each invocation, then we have something to talk about performance wise.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yes agreed.....

Comment: This is primarily opinion based, but I usually favor the builder pattern for these type of configuration constructions.